# push vs. bundle vs. tar zcvf -- to backup entire local .git

Tags: git

I can backup my local .git by pushing it to a repository in two steps:

```
git push --all ~/gitrepo
git push --tags ~/gitrepo
```

I can back it up using [git bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129214/backup-a-local-git-repository).

I can back it up by simply copying the entire directory or archiving it (compressed!):

```
tar -zcvf gitrepo.tgz .git
```

And there are probably [additional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4372832/what-is-the-best-way-to-back-up-an-entire-git-repository-on-external-disk) ways to backup an [entire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4658451/can-a-local-git-clone-be-considered-a-complete-backup-of-the-repo-it-was-cloned-f) local .git.

The question now is whether they are really equivalent? (for example, the `logs` subdirectory isn't pushed)

What are the advantages of the `git push` method vs. `git bundle`?

Can `tar -zcvf` be considered "the perfect git backup"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regarding `tar`: It saves everything: the config (remote URLs), the reflogs, etc.  You might want the reflogs if you accidentally do something really stupid in your repository *and* your hard drive crashes shortly afterwards.  Far-fetched, but `tar` is easy and it does everything. Use `tar` for making backups, use `git push` for making mirrors.  These are different kinds of tasks.

Regarding compression: I have a 27M git repo, almost entirely plain text, and the `.tar.gz` is... also 27M.  That's not a whole lot of savings.

Comment: All answers were excellent: @VonC introduced me to `--mirror` and `stash`. @sehe clarified `bundle` and you pointed out the difference between a *backup* and a *mirror* (plus the interesting fact that a git repo is already in compressed form?). SO only allows accepting 1 answer and you have the least number of points, so I am accepting yours. :)

Comment: I used tar for git backup, but now i wanted to migrate some repos on other server and untared repos are giving me strange errors. Did any of you got this errors?

Comment: If anybody gets strange errors like

error: refs/remotes/origin/master does not point to a valid object!
error: Trying to write ref refs/heads/master with nonexistant object

after untaring repo and while trying to git pull, you should check you git version.

Apparently, you need git with at least 1.7.11 version and that will solve you problems.

Comment: FYI: If you `tar -zcvf gitrepo.tgz .git` you will not backup any untracked files -- i.e., files that have not been added to the repo

Answer (score 8):

I use Git bundle

```
git bundle create /tmp/backup.git --all --tags --remotes
```

You can receive it as if it were a repo:

```
cd myworktree
git pull /tmp/backup.git
```

---

But also see

- [How to update a git clone --mirror?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150188/how-to-update-a-git-clone-mirror/6151901#6151901)
- ["fetch --all" in a git bare repository doesn't synchronize local branches to the remote ones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5559321/fetch-all-in-a-git-bare-repository-doesnt-synchronize-local-branches-to-the/5559586#5559586)
- [Git doesn't clone all branches on subsequent clones?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5563349/git-doesnt-clone-all-branches-on-subsequent-clones/5563660#5563660)

---

#### Completeness, notes

For *complete* backup (thing of git-rerere cache, stashes, hooks, configuration files) I suggest using **[`rsync`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync)**

```
rsync -hxPavilyzH --stats --delete .git/ backup@remote:/repo/mirror.git/
```

Alternatively:

- [Is it possible to push a git stash to a remote repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1550378)
- copy the rerere cache directory

Answer (score 5):

The tar method is a possibility, but it won't check the integrity of the saved repo: you won't know if that compressed repo would work until you uncompress it and try to clone or fetch from it.

I prefer the [clone --mirror](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4686392/backup-all-branches-in-a-git-repository-keeping-what-has-been-rebased-and-forced) approach (with reflogs enabled in the resulting bare repo).
And the incremental backups are then simple push.
As debated in this [old thread](http://kerneltrap.org/mailarchive/git/2008/5/12/1799564), a [`git stash`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash) before a backup might allow you to save more (index and working tree state)