# git how to clean a cloned repository and reclone

Tags: windows, git

I am using a usb that i have cloned my repo, so i can transfer my work at home and vice versa. Many times the usb has problems and corrupts the repository. If I try to clean it and reclone it shows all the old (self) files as deleted, and all the origin's files as modified.

I tried to clean the cloned repo by deleting folder or rename it, or event delete .git and reclone but it still shows old files as deleted. Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Unless you work on the USB key directly, the `.git` folder is all that ever matters. The working copy is not relevant, because it's not used by anything. A "corruption" only happens if `git fsck` tells you there is a problem, but I don't think that's the case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would really recommend, in order to have a clean version of your repo, to [make a bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129214/backup-a-local-git-repository/2129286#2129286).
(See [`git bundle` man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-bundle)).
Make sure you [don't forget tags as well in your bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5719369/git-bundle-bundle-tags-and-heads/5720366#5720366).
Alternatives are discussed at "[push vs. bundle vs. tar zcvf — to backup entire local .git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6702057/push-vs-bundle-vs-tar-zcvf-to-backup-entire-local-git)".

That way, you get only *one* file to backup on your usb key (and you can clone/fetch from that bundle file).
One file is much harder to corrupt ;)

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't quite get though, how I could update bundle with commits from MachineB and then fetch them from MachineA

Comment: @dotoree I found re-creating the bundle from scratch easier than trying to update an existing bundle. Indeed, You cannot easily push to a bundle. However, once (re)created and saved on your USB key, it behaves like a bare repo, and you can pull from that bundle that very same way that you would from a bare repo: add to your machine A a remote repo (git remote add usbrepo /path/to/bundle) and pull from it.

Answer (score 2):

You should be using a **bare** repository, that is one without a work tree, on the USB key. Bare repository is created with `git init --bare` or `git clone --bare`.

The "corruption" you are seeing is because git push does not update working directory of a non-bare target repository. If the working copy is checked out from the branch you are pushing, it will result in invalid state of the working copy.

However, there is absolutely no reason to have a working copy there unless you mean to work directly from the USB key. So just don't create it, it's not needed for anything.

If on the other hand you do intend to work off the USB key, either always pull to it (which does update the working copy, of course) or install appropriate hooks to update the working copy (there are two ways, depending on how you intend to work with it).

Comment: I used bare at first on USB. Bundle is so much neat and tidy.