# Copying existing git repository onto an external hard drive

Tags: git

As per the title, I have been working with a git repo on my work system. I would like to work on the same repo at home as well. Would anything go wrong if i just transfer the entire git repo folder onto my external hard drive and work on it between my work and home computer?

I am still in the process of pushing everything on to github, work internet is really slow so bringing it back home to push it to the github repo is another benefit as well.

Comment: A git repository is entirely self contained, so there are no problems if you copy the entire folder onto an external drive.

Comment: Just be sure you get the *entire* folder, including the hidden `.git` folder and all its contents.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is a git folder self-contained?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14181402/is-a-git-folder-self-contained)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I copy a Git working copy onto another machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2042470/can-i-copy-a-git-working-copy-onto-another-machine)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can just copy the `.git` folder to your hard drive. So when you want to get the exact files, you can copy back the `.git` folder to your computer and inside the new empty directory, run `git checkout .` to get the files back.

But the better approach is assume the hard drive directory as a `git remote`, to doing this, you can make a directory inside your hard drive, run `git init` on it. Define `remote` to your hard drive directory path and `push` your existing repository into that. Therefore in another system, you can `pull | clone` the repository (directory in your hard drive) and interact with that directory as a `git remote`